# Why is $V$ a neighborhood of $p$?

Tags: real-analysis

this is a proof for theorem that compact subsets of metric spaces are closed.
I can't understand the line: If $V$ is intersection of $V_{q1}$, $V_{q2}$, $\dots$ , $V_{qn}$,
then $V$ is a neighborhood of $p$.

I don't think being intersections of neighborhood doesn't mean it is a neighborhood.

Pleas help me understand this!

> **$\mathbf{2.34}\,\,\,$Theorem** *Compact subsets of metric spaces are closed.*
>
> **Proof$\,\,\,$** Let $K$ be a compact subset of a metric space $X$. We shall prove that the complement of $K$ is an open subset of $X$.
>
> Suppose $p\in X$, $p\notin K$. If $q\in K$, let $V_q$ and $W_q$ be neighborhoods of $p$ and $q$, respectively, of radius less than $\frac{1}{2}d(p,q)$ [see Definition $2.18\text{(a)}$]. Since $K$ is compact, there are finitely many points $q_1,\ldots,q_n$ in $K$ such that $$K\subset W_{q1}\cup\cdots\cup W_{qn}=W.$$ If $V=V_{q1}\cap\cdots\cap V_{qn}$, then $V$ is a neighborhood of $p$ which does not intersect $W$. Hence $V\subset K^{c}$, so that $p$ is an interior point of $K^{c}$. The theorem follows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On page 32, Rudin defines a neighborhood $N_r(p)$ of $p$ to be the set

$$N_r(p) = \{q \in X : d(p, q) < r\}$$

which is an open disk.  Since all $V_{q_i}$ are open disks centered at $p$, it follows immediately that $ V = \bigcap V_{q_i}$ is the smallest of these open disks.

Answer (score 1):

Finite intersection of neighborhoods of a point $x$ is still a neighborhood of $x$.

Try to prove it, using the definition:
 $U$ is a *neighborhood* of $x$ iff there is $\varepsilon>0$ such that $\{y\mid d(x,y)<\varepsilon\}\subseteq U$.

> **Hint:** use the *minimum* of the epsilons given with all $V_{q_i}$.